# MoveTowards not working properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to move toward each object from my array, I mean move first to [0] then [1] and so on. I'm having problems with animations.

```
function exit( path : Array){
    var node : Node;
    var go : GameObject;

    for(var i=1 ; i < path.length ; i++){
        node = path[i] as Node;
        go = node.getContent() as GameObject;
        nodeS.getContent().transform.position =  Vector3.MoveTowards(nodeS.getContent().transform.position, go.transform.position  ,1);
    }
}
```

I call exit function inside `Update()`. As a result, I'm getting weird movements, and I understand that the problem is between for loop and Update function.

Comment: What do you mean with "weird movements"? Does it move like it is snapping or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the weird movements, because in each `Update()` (each call of your `exit()`), you go over all of the nodes in the `path` and *move just one step* towards them. It's because [Vector3.MoveTowards](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) only calculates the next step of the movement from *current* to *target*. The size of your step is "1" (the third parameter of `Vector3.MoveTowards()`)

So basically, in each `Update()`, this happens:

- move 1 unit closer to the first node of `path`
- move 1 unit closer to the second node of `path`
- move 1 unit closer to the third node of `path`
- and so on

So, I'd do it somehow like this:

```
function exit(path : Array) {

    var node : Node;
    var go : GameObject;

    node = path[CurrentNodeIndex] as Node;
    go : GameObject = node.getContent() as GameObject;


    if (!Mathf.Approximately(
            Vector3.Distance(nodeS.getContent().transform.position, go.transform.position),
            0
    )) {

        nodeS.getContent().transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(nodeS.getContent().transform.position, go.transform.position, 1);

    } else {
        CurrentNodeIndex++;
        Debug.Log("Starting to move towards next node: " + CurrentNodeIndex);

        if (CurrentNodeIndex >= path.length) {
            Debug.Log("The final node was reached!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**What this does:**

1. Get the first node from the `path` (`CurrentNodeIndex` is 1 at the beginning)
2. if the current distance between this node and nodeS (using `Vector3.Distance`) is not approximately 0 (using `Mathf.Approximately`), move one step closer to the node (using `Vector3.MoveTowards`)
3. this is called every Update until the distance between the two nodes is approximately 0. Then the `CurrentNodeIndex` is increased.
4. in next Update, select the next node from `path` and repeat the process - start moving towards it
5. when the last node from `path` was reached, just return. You can also have some global private bool flag indicating this and optimize

Please forgive any compilation errors; I don't use Unityscript, but C#, and have no means to test it right now.

BTW, is there any reason why you start taking notes from `path` with index 1 and not 0? If you meant to start with the actual first node of `path`, initialize `CurrentNodeIndex` to 0 instead of 1.